# <cfinclude> and relative positions

Tags: railo, lucee

I have an application that when the request arrives at a particular file, its relative position out by one folder.  If I try to include a file from the folder above

```
   <cfinclude template="../file.cfm">
```

fails, but

```
   <cfinclude template="../../file.cfm">
```

works.

If I request the file directly the "../file.cfm" works as expected.  And if I recreate the the stack using alternative files it also works as expected.

So it seems to me there is something in the code that is causing the file's relative position to be different.

Is that possible?  This is relative and I'm not using any mappings.

If not then something is broken and I'll have to try something else.  Sorry I can't post any code to demonstrate.

Ta

Chris

Comment: Difficult to say really but I would say that you have a configuration issue somewhere. Can you give any details of the environment, e.g. OS, Railo/Lucee version, Java container you are using and version, etc...?

Comment: I'll take that as  maybe.  
It's:
    Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Version of Railo/Lucee? Java container (e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, Resin, etc..)? JVM version?

Comment: I'll take that as  maybe.  
It's:
    Ubuntu 14.04
    Railo 4.2.1.008 final
    Tomcat 7
But prime suspect is that it's a VirtualBox VM on my workstation using Guest Additions shared folder to the htdocs and custom tags files on a windows share.

I was asking the question that way to get a quick yes/no wrt possibility of something in the code.  As that's probably not it I'm going to ditch Virtual Box VM idea ad try a real Windows box.

Comment: That is a similar set up to what some of my team here at mso use and we've not had this problem so I'm not sure that is going to be the issue, but of course it might be. The code snippet you posted simply suggests the file is actually two directories up from where you are calling it. It is not something like you have an include inside another include and it is using the path from the original include to locate the file, if you see what I mean?

Comment: Well, it's a working CFMX application, has been for years.  I'm just trying to get it running under Railo/Lucee.

So yes it's an include in a line a quite a few other includes.  The code works in the ACF environment (which is much more simple and all on the same box).

Comment: Are there any symlinks or does the web server have virtual directories with the same name as physical directories but in a different & conflicting location?

Comment: the web server is using folders mounted by VirtualBox guest additions

/media/sf_websfolder/...

They are given 770 permissions by VirtualBox as owned by root:vboxsf  so I've added users: railo and www-data into the vboxsf group, so they has read-write-execute access to the files

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think is that somehow you are conflating the URL in the address bar with the notion of file system paths.

A `<cfinclude>` relative path is relative to the file it's included from, nothing else.

Using your own examples:

```
<!--- thisFile.cfm --->
<cfinclude template="../file.cfm">
```

This will work in this sort of file hierarchy:

```
/base/
    /subdir/
        thisFile.cfm
    file.cfm
```

(where `subdir` can be anything and can also be abstracted by any depth in a directory structure, provided `file.cfm` is always in the same directory as `subdir`)

```
<!--- thisFile.cfm --->
<cfinclude template="../../file.cfm">
```

In this situation, the file structure would need to be like this:

```
/base/
    /subdir/
        /anotherSubDir/
            thisFile.cfm
    file.cfm
```

(same rules apply as above, just abstracted by one further subdirectory).

But relative paths are *always* relative to the source code file the `<cfinclude>` is in. Nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, I know it sounds ridiculous for you to have to spell that out.  That's what I've known for 18 years myself :)

Comment: OK, well you're not telling us something then. I recommend that - for the purposes of testing this - you factor-out VirtualBox from the equation (just in case... although I doubt it is contributing), and just "install" Lucee Express (download, unzip & run, so no real hardship) and replicate the issue on a local file system with no additional "moving parts". Also, can you update your question to show exactly where the files are in your file system (like how I do in my answer). Also include *exact* code which demonstrates the issue. Not code samples, but actual, complete code. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I am removing VirtualBox .  I may be a short while before I respond back here but as soon as I know more I will update the post and process this until solved.